# How to parse websites that use angularjs?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, parsing, nokogiri

I want to know how to parse a website that using angularjs as its front end framework.

The following code parses http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites to get the course title.

What I got is `{{course.title}}` instead of the actual course title. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites"))
title = doc.css("h1").first.text
puts title       # => {{course.title}}
```

Comment: if site has proper SEO set up can try finding the proper `_escaped_fragment_` path as outlined by google ajax search docs. Alternatively can use a headless browser

Answer (score 1):

Google has good docs on how to set up SEO for ajax driven sites. The site in question has followed these guidelines.

Using the `<base>` tag of that page as a path reference you can access rendered html using this path:

```
http://www.pluralsight.com/courses?_escaped_fragment=/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites
```

Reference: [Google Ajax Crawling Spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

As an alternative you can use a headless browser to render the page and use that as your source

Comment: Hi Charlie, I tried to use the URL you provided with my demo code and still got the same result. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: not sure without doing a comparison of the view/source output and the live html in browser devtools inspector. It may be that they haven't properyly integrated raw html output ( which is what it should be for search engines). You will probably have to resort to using a headless browser on your server

Comment: The URL example is wrong. The good URL is http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites?_escaped_fragment_=.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
require 'phantomjs'
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)
b.goto URL

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(b.html)

@title = doc.css('h1').first.text
```

Download phantomjs in http://phantomjs.org/download.html and move the binary for /usr/bin